# Absolute position relative to a container that is also responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having some trouble positioning an element to its parent absolutely while keeping it responsive. Lets just say I have a responsive `<section>` that is 66% of the screen width and centered. I have a `<nav>` that is supposed to be stuck to the side of it at all times. However once your screen size is less than 992px, the width of that `<section>` is now 100%. The `<nav>` that is supposed to be always on the side is now supposed to be stuck to the top of the `<section>`...

All of this I can do and make it work properly... until you keep shrinking the size of the screen down where the `<li>` 's in the `<nav>` have to stack on top of eachother. When this happens the `<nav>` is now covering part of the `<section>` instead of remaining aligned with it.

I have made a [**codepen with an example of this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNZNmB?editors=110). I gave the elements background colors so its easier to see whats happening.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Is there a way I can do this without controlling it with multiple media queries?

#### HTML

```
<section class="col-8-12 offset-2">
  <nav class="to-do-list">
    <ul>
      <li>Add Some1 Info</li>
      <li>Add Some2 Info</li>
      <li>Add Some3 Info</li>
      <li>Add Some4 Info</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <h1>Some Title Here</h1>
    <p>Some1 Stuff Here</p>
    <p>Some2 Stuff Here</p>
    <p>Some3 Stuff Here</p>
    <p>Some4 Stuff Here</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
html              { background-color: #1394cb; }
.col-8-12         { width: 66.66666667%; }
.offset-2         { margin-left: 16.66666667%; }
section           { float: left; margin-top: 250px; background-color: #0d2c41; position: relative; }
nav.to-do-list    { position: absolute; left: -177px; top: 0; background-color: #FFF; max-width: 180px; }
div>h1, div>p     { color: #FFF; padding-left: 15px; }
ul>li             { list-style: none; margin-right: 30px; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
  .col-8-12       { width: 100%; }
  .offset-2       { margin-left: 0; }
  nav.to-do-list  { left: 0; top: -50px; min-height: 50px; display: inline-block; max-width: none; width: 95%; margin-left: 2.5%; }
  ul>li           { display: inline-block; }
}
```

Comment: I think you will need a second media query for new behavior starting at the max-width where it starts to cover the main section. Any time you resize the window and the design starts to break, that's where you should be adding a break point (a new media query). That is the fundamental tenet behind responsive design.

Comment: @TylerH I understand that I can do that, however the <nav> contains different elements that are all different sizes. I would need like 5+ media queries to handle it and was trying to see if there is a better solution than that (like a percentage absolute position or something)

Comment: I'd be switching the sidebar to position: relative for mobile. This puts it back in the flow and pushes the other content down below it.

Comment: Just remove absolute positioning on narrow resolutions and figure out the rest of the positioning from there, no need to make it complicated.

Comment: @Nit would you care to give an example? did you look at the codepen? putting relative positioning doesn't change a thing. and I'm trying to keep it simple and not complicated... if I use media queries I'll need at least 5 because the elements inside the <nav> are not just <li>'s theres multiple different sized elements. I was trying to get some help to see if theres a different way to do it than my current approach, before I go making a bunch of custom media queries for this one element

Comment: Using relative positioning solves your whole problem if you figure out of the rest of the positioning from there. The issue is trivial as far as I can see? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYzLWE

Comment: @Nit Oh gotcha, so top 0 left 0 relative with a min-height does it. interesting. if you post an answer i'll accept it. In my original question i said I was really new to responsive designs and css / html so its something thats more difficult for me to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use relative positioning at lower resolutions. Using absolute will break your layout because the element is removed from the regular flow and therefore doesn't affect other elements around it.
With minor other modifications:

```
html { background-color: #1394cb; }
.col-8-12 { width: 66.66666667%; }
.offset-2 { margin-left: 16.66666667%; }
section { float: left; margin-top: 250px; ; position: relative; }
section > div {background: #0d2c41; padding: 10px 0;}
nav.to-do-list { position: absolute; left: -177px; top: 0; background-color: #FFF; max-width: 180px; }
div>h1, div>p { color: #FFF; padding-left: 15px; }

ul>li { list-style: none; margin-right: 30px; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
  .col-8-12 { width: 100%; }
  .offset-2 { margin-left: 0; }
  nav.to-do-list { position: relative; left: 0; min-height: 50px; display: inline-block; max-width: none; width: 95%; margin-left: 2.5%; }
  ul>li { display: inline-block; }
}
```

Comment: there is an issue with this. the positioning is contained inside the section. the reason why I had absolute positioning in the first place was to move the nav outside of the section. thoughts? [**PEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNZPLd?editors=110)

Comment: Why do you need it that way? Just use the div in section as you would've used section originally.

Comment: because the div is one small component inside the section... I hate using markup to style the page, but i may have to do that in this case just leads to crappy markup